# bootstrap modal box not work in remote tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I work with [bootstrap remote tabs](https://github.com/thecodeassassin/bootstrap-remote-data/blob/master/js/bootstrap-remote-tabs.js) plugin and need to load `$.ajax` modal box link into each remote tabs like this :

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">No remote data</a></li>
    <li><a href="#simple" data-toggle="tab" data-tab-url="remote/normal.html">Simple remote data</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="71" class="push info" title="Full Image">check modal</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="simple"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(function() {

            $('.push').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'remote/remote.php', // in here you should put your query 
                    data: {'bookid' : id,'lang' : 'en'}, // here you pass your id via ajax .
                    // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
                    success: function(r) {
                        // now you can show output in your modal 
                        $('#bookdetails').modal({
                                backdrop: 'static',
                                keyboard: false
                            }) // put your modal id 
                        $('.something').show().html(r);
                    }
                });


            });

        });
    });
```

In reality first tabs is worked and show remote value into modalbox but when I click another tabs I see link but after click in, modalbox not shown and not work with remote link. how do fix this ?

NOTE: please click in `check modal` link for remote tabs

Live [demo](http://farhangishop.com/tabs/demo/)

Comment: [How ti use a Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). You missed attributes (`data-toggle  and data-target`) on anchor link .

Comment: @JSantosh: can u tell me what's your mean ?! please edit my code for your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue . You are binding `.push` element when page loaded in first tab, so the first modal is working and in second tab whichis remote tab, the `.push` element in not bound. So

Your JS should be like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.push', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'remote/remote.php', // in here you should put your query 
    data: {
      'bookid': id,
      'lang': 'en'
    }, // here you pass your id via ajax .
    // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
    success: function(r) {
      // now you can show output in your modal 
      $('#bookdetails').modal({
          backdrop: 'static',
          keyboard: false
        }) // put your modal id 
      $('.something').show().html(r);
    }
  });
});
```